# Front page welcome message area

Tags: frontpage

How i can create a welcome message area for my frontpage with backend control {admin panel}

### Welcome

message

Comment: Are you able to modify your template files, or are you looking for a plug and play solution?

Comment: Please improve your question: Where and how do want to add that content: editing the theme, installing a plugin? Show us your research efforts.

Comment: Dear Toscho i want to edit the theme not plugin , i do research !! . i need to make it option using theme option

Comment: dear pippin as i answered i need to edit the theme

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a page theme, then call it in `index.php`:

```
$recent = new WP_Query( 'page_id=**ID**' ); 
while ( $recent->have_posts() ) : $recent->the_post();
    ?><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3><?php 
    the_content();
endwhile;
```

Comment: <?php $recent = new WP_Query("page_id=**ID**"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
       <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
       <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

Comment: You can edit your own answer to make corrections and updates... Also, use the proper formatting for code.

Answer (score 0):

Put a loop on the front page limited to posts with the tag "welcomeMessage". Then, on the back end write a post with that tag. Edit the post whenever you want to change the message.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a static frontpage, you can add the message to a custom field on the post editing screen and then put a shortcode in the page to display it, e.g. `[welcome-message]`.

```
add_shortcode( 'welcome-message', 'echo_welcome_message' );
function echo_welcome_message() {
    global $post; 
    return get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'welcomemessage', true );
}
```

I don't see how this is really much different than just adding the welcome message to the top of the page content, but hope it helps.